# An imported function won't work in a Node Worker Thread because the dependency graph isn't loaded

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, es6-modules, node-worker-threads

I'm trying to use Node's `worker_threads` using [`node-worker-threads-pool`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-worker-threads-pool) (*a wrapper*) package and its `DynamicPool`.

My issue is that executing a thread giving a function which has `import`s won't work because that function will be `undefined`.

```
// moduleA.js
import xyz from './xyz.js'

const f = x => {
   xyz () //<-- f is undefined
}

export default f

// moduleB.js
import f from './moduleA.js'


f (1) // 

// moduleC.js
const x = await pool.exec ({
   task: f
})
```

Is this an specific issue of  [`node-worker-threads-pool`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-worker-threads-pool) or Node's `worker_threads`? Do you know some approach to workaround this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a limitation of [the library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-worker-threads-pool), and has nothing to do with modules:

> Notice: If `task` is a function, you can not use closure in it! If you do want to use external data in the function, you can use workerData to pass some cloneable data.

This sounds a lot like they are stringifying the function and creating a worker from that code only.

Use a worker file instead.

Comment: I've found myself in a situation on which Node isn't capable enough. Worker Threads should be fine, but these can't be interactively debugged. It's not the end of the world, because I've implemented the project using pure FP and I handle effects. BTW; clearly it's not very suitable for parallel computations because of the limitations of the nature of Node and JS programming.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check `workerpool` [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/workerpool?activeTab=readme)
and create `Dedicated Workers`, I was running into similar issue and this solved it